# How to get a HTML element from a string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to get a HTML element from a string that contains HTML. Is it possible to use a jQuery selector to do this?

I have a Javascript function that gets an entire page from the server, but I only need one element from that page.

Comment: Can you share what exactly you mean by string and how does it appear?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you have. Does the string contain HTML code for a single element, or does it contain code for several elements of which you want to get one?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yes, you can turn the string into elements, and select elements from it. Example:

```
var elements = $(theHtmlString);
var found = $('.FindMe', elements);
```

Comment: This is called using `elements` as the [ **context** ](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). It is internally implemented with [ **.find()** ](http://api.jquery.com/find/) , so an equivalent way to write the above is: `var found = elements.find('.FindMe');`

Comment: This method (`$('selector', $('html string'))`) doesn't seem to work for me in jQ:1.6.2

Comment: Nevermind this occured because as you said it is using `find()`, whereas I needed it to use `closest()`, perhaps jQ should be amended.  **Problem Case:** `$('pre', $('<pre><div>foo</div></pre><pre><div>bar</div></pre>'));`.  Because it uses find, which only looks at the children, it'll never find any `pre`s.  Easiest solution is to add a wrap.

Comment: @vol7ron thanks so much for explaining that for me; this was driving me batty!

Comment: What's the difference this and `$(theHtmlString).find('.FindMe')` ?

Comment: @AlexG: Using `elements.find(selector)` does the same as `$(selector, elements)`.

Comment: If your html has dot ( . ) or single quote ( ' ) character, this doesn't work

Comment: @Guffa i am having a string '(parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)+((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)*((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[4][8]\']").val())||0))/100)', here i want to find which elements are involved then how can i get that?

Comment: `found` can have multiple elements, how can you get the value of elements in `found` ?

Answer (score 21):

Just wrap the html text in the $ function. Like

```
$("<div>I want this element</div>")
```

Comment: I love you for telling me that this is possible.  This just solved all my problems.

Comment: @KingErronnneous i am having a string '(parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)+((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)*((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[4][8]\']").val())||0))/100)', here i want to find which elements are involved then how can i get that

Answer (score 12):

If you are loading a page dynamically from a server then you can target just one element from the loaded page using the following form with **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

```
$(selectorWhereToShowNewData).load('pagePath selectorForElementFromNewData');
```

For example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Where:
`#result` is where the loaded page part will be displayed on the current page
`ajax/test.html` is the URL to which the server request is sent
`#container` is the element on the response page you want to display. Only that will be loaded into the element `#result`. The rest of the response page will not be displayed.

Comment: i am having a string '(parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)+((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[3][7]\']").val())||0)*((parseFloat($("#assumptions_table").find("[name=\'assumptions[4][8]\']").val())||0))/100)', here i want to find which elements are involved then how can i get that

Answer (score 11):

Just use $.filter

```
var html = "<div><span class='im-here'></span></div>"
var found = $(html).filter(".im-here")
```

Comment: The `filter` method works even if the element you want happens to be the outer-most element.  The `find` method only finds _descendants_, so it would _not_ match the outer-most element.  In the example in this answer, you could _not_ use the `find` method to get the `div`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.find`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var htmlVal = "<div><span class='im-here'>Span Value</span></div>";
  var spanElement = $(htmlVal).find("span");
  var spanVal = spanElement.text();

  alert(spanVal);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `$.find`—but only if you want just elements inside the outermost element, the `div' in this example.  The `find` method only matches _descendants_.  You could not `find` the `div` in this example--but, you can `filter` the `div` because the `filter` method matches any/all elements, including the outermost `div`.