# Get jQuery object from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I have an AJAX request that grabs the source of Wikipedia pages:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "TrollWikipedia.ashx",
    data: {
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20s",
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function (html) {
        var page = $(html);
        alert(page.find("#content").length); //Alerts 0
        alert(page.html()); //alerts null
    }
});
```

It successfully returns the source of the page (I have a copy of the string it returns [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PddX/)).

The problem: I can't seem to make a jQuery object from the HTML (like they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery)). For some reason, it doesn't seem to be creating the object correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd imagine the jQuery regex determining if the value is HTML is failing somehow. Is the HTML coming from Wikipedia properly formed? Alternatively, you could always stuff that in a `<script type="text/html">` element and try querying from inside that. Just a thought.

Comment: @Tejs You can inspect the jsFiddle link and see if the HTML is properly formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html data seems to be badly parsed (maybe a closing div tag is missing in the html code), use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "TrollWikipedia.ashx",
    data: {
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20s",
    },
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (html) {

        html=html.replace(/(<body [^>]*>)/i, '$1<div>').replace(/(<\/body>)/i, '</div>$1');
        var page = $(html);
        alert($("#content",page).length); //Alerts 1
        alert(page.html()); //alerts html
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. :( Note that `dataType` is case-sensitive.

Comment: what is return by adding: alert(html); ?

Answer (score 0):

`html` string contains the links pointing to `en.wikipedia.org` site, so when we do `$(html)` `jQuery` might be getting exception due to cross domain script calls inside the html markup due to which you are not getting any thing after `$(html)`

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that would be the reason. If it is, how would I fix it?

Comment: I dont think there is any way to fix it unless you use iframe and load the page inside iframe.