# How to filter out an object between the <script> tag

Tags: javascript

I am using a web crawler to fetch data. Now I have a string with HTML content and I need need to get an object that is in between the tag:

**string**

```
var targetString = 
" <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head></head>
  <body class="">Body Content
    <script type="text/javascript">objectName = {foo: 5};</script> 
  </body>
  </html>
";
```

How can I get out `objectName` out of this string, and get it to a readable object, such that I can call out 'foo' in a consistent matter?

Comment: In what host environment?

Comment: @johnandrews can you explain your problem? either string is a html code or simple string? if you can show string example than i think it will be easy to guide.

Comment: javascript. basically I just have a string such as "fjkssfkjfsjk<script type=text/javascript>object</script>" and want a way to filter out that object.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan thanks, but my string is superlong. Le me rewrite

Comment: i think this will guide you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery

Comment: thanks, any pure JS solutions? dont like jQuery so much

Comment: you must see (Javascript HTML DOM Elements) getElementsByTagName and getElementById in Javascript.

Comment: oke thanks! but the script tag is not a dom element right?

Comment: Script is a tag and you can handle it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call `.match()` on `targetString` , with `RegExp` `/\{.*\}/` as argument ; call `.replace()` string at index `0` of returned array from `.match()` with `RegExp` `/(\w+)(?=:)/` , with replacement string wrapping match in escaped double quotes `"\"$1\""` ; call `JSON.parse()` on returned string from `.replace()`

```js
var targetString = ' <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->'
  + '<head></head>'
  + '<body class="">Body Content'
  +  '<script type="text/javascript">objectName = {foo: 5};<\/script>' 
  + '</body>'
  + '</html>'; 

var objectName = JSON.parse(
                   targetString
                   // match left bracket "{" ,
                   // followed by any single character
                   // except the newline characters
                   // 0 or more times
                   // followed by right bracket "}"
                   .match(/\{.*\}/)[0]
                   // match any alphanumeric character
                   // 1 or more times
                   // set replacement string as
                   // captured any alphanumeric character
                   // wrapped within escaped double quotes 
                   // on either side of replacement string
                   .replace(/(\w+)(?=:)/,"\"$1\"")
                 );

console.log(objectName);

document.write(JSON.stringify(objectName, null, 2));

document.write("<br>" + objectName.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
var result=targetstring.split("objectName");
alert(result[1]);
```

or something like that depending upon your need; just use the `split()` function.

split function reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JS code in your question is malformed and should be like this:

```js
var targetString = 
' <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->\
  <head></head>\
  <body class="">Body Content\
    <script type="text/javascript">objectName = {foo: 5};</script>\
  </body>\
  </html>\
';
```

If you know exactly this is how your input will be look like(there won't be anything else in the `<script>` tag except the assignment), you can simply use regular expressions to extract your data object:

```js
var pattern = /<script [^>]*>[\w_]+\s*=\s*(.*?);?<\/script>/;
eval('(' + targetString.match(pattern)[1] + ')');
```

If you are only aware of the variable name in your script and there might be other statements in it, you can throw the whole thing into an `<iframe>` and extract the object value like this:

```js
var targetString = 
' <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->\
<head></head>\
<body class="">Body Content\
<script type="text/javascript">objectName = {foo: 5};</script>\
</body>\
</html>\
';

var context = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(context);
context.contentWindow.document.write(targetString);
console.log(context.contentWindow.objectName); // got it
document.body.removeChild(context);
```

[See demo here.](http://jsbin.com/banijinake/1/edit)