# getting html element using selector before it render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"></div></div>'

console.log($(x).find('#container').html())
```

I wonder why this doesn't work, I just want to extract the html before it's append to somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work, it returns an empty string for me, which is just as expected as `#container` doesn't contain any HTML at all ?

Comment: did you checked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `html` in `#container`. If you want to get the `#container` itself  then you can do it with `outerHTML` like following.

```
var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"></div></div>';
console.log($(x).find('#container')[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery html api is for ( Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element. - http://api.jquery.com/html/)

your code is right, if you want to get "container" html, you have to call other function. e.g) get(0)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"></div></div>';
  console.log($(x).find('#container').get(0));
});
```

if you want to add something or object, you can use append API.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"></div></div>'; // string
  var $x = $(x); //$x is a jQuery object
  $x.find('#container').append($('<div>test</div>'));
  console.log($x);
});
```

Comment: how can I append it to somewhere else? I got object using get(0);