# Selecting elements within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string:

```
var html = '<select">\
<option></option>\
<option>Mr</option>\
<option>Mrs</option>\
<option>Ms</option>\
<option>Master</option>\
<option>Miss</option>\
<option>Dr</option>\
<option>TBA</option>\
</select>';
```

I'm wanting to place a `selected` within the 'Master' option. How could I do this?

I've tried:

```
var html = $($(html).find("option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Master"; }).prop('selected', true));
```

I don't know how to search  a string like I would the DOM.

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hovawubowi/edit?js,console,output)**

Comment: what is the `html` output?

Comment: can you add values to the options? It would be easier to mark as "selected"

Comment: Convert it to a dom node and then you can traverse it like you would any other dom tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do a string replace like this:

`html = html.replace('<option>Master</option>','<option selected>Master</option>');`

Comment: quick and easy FTW

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector and set attribute using **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
$(this).html() == "Master";
}).prop('selected', true));
var html = '<select>\
<option></option>\
<option>Mr</option>\
<option>Mrs</option>\
<option>Ms</option>\
<option>Master</option>\
<option>Miss</option>\
<option>Dr</option>\
<option>TBA</option>\
</select>';

console.log(
  $(html)
  .find('option:contains("Master")') // getoption which contains master
  .attr('selected', true) // set selected attribute
  .end()[0].outerHTML // back to previous selector and get dom  object and it's outerHTML property
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

With  **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method

```js
var html = '<select>\
<option></option>\
<option>Mr</option>\
<option>Mrs</option>\
<option>Ms</option>\
<option>Master</option>\
<option>Miss</option>\
<option>Dr</option>\
<option>TBA</option>\
</select>';

console.log(
  $(html)
  .find("option") // get all options
  .filter(function() { // filter option which contains master
    return $(this).text() == "Master";
  }).attr('selected', true) // set selected attribute
  .end() // back to option selector
  .end()[0].outerHTML // back to html selector and get dom  object and it's outerHTML property
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
/*jshint multistr: true */
var html = 
 '<select class="form-control honorific">\
   <option>Mr</option>\
   <option>Mrs</option>\
   <option>Ms</option>\
   <option>Master</option>\
   <option>Miss</option>\
   <option>Dr</option>\
   <option>TBA</option>\
 </select>';

$(function() {
    var temp = "Master"; 
    $('body').append(html);
    $(".form-control").val(temp);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what this wil do?

Comment: Find element with class name is `.form-control` (it should be a id) and set value (default selected) for it is `Master`

Answer (score -2):

This may help :

```
var elements = $(theHtmlString);
var found = $('.FindMe', elements);
```

Source:[How to get an HTML element from a string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery)

Comment: Because this answer the specific question. It only shows how to select a specific element but not how to add an attribute or anything.