# jQuery get value from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in jQuery that looks like this...

```
var myvariable = '<iframe id="myiframe" class="thisiframe">';
```

I am trying to extract the id from this so looking to get 'myiframe'

What is the best way of doing this, should I be using regex or is there a jQuery function that would be better to use?

Or can I target the iframe directly using this variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an HTML element from a string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery)

Comment: Use the string as a selector.

Comment: `$(myvariable).attr('id') `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create DOM element using [`$(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) method and then use various method to get `.attr()` or  `.prop()`

```js
var myvariable = '<iframe id="myiframe" class="thisiframe">';
var ifrme = $(myvariable);
console.log(ifrme.attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, you can do this is native Javascript as well.

```
document.querySelector('iframe').id
```

The bit between the quotes is what's known as a CSS selector. In this instance I'm selecting the iframe using it's element type (which is iframe), but you could use a class instead, such as  `document.querySelector('.thisisiframe')`.

And you can test this code all in the browser under the Console in Dev Tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
console.log($(myvariable).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try once:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myvariable = '<iframe id="myiframesss" class="thisiframe">';
    alert($(myvariable).attr('id'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If format is going to be same then you can simply try this. This would work in this condition.

Note: This is not a proper solution, however, would work fine in this case

```
myvariable.substr(myvariable.indexOf('id="')+4,(myvariable.indexOf('" '))-myvariable.indexOf('id="')-4)
```