# Extract Text and Specific Elements from a String Containing HTML

Tags: jquery, html

There's a similar thread here, but it only deals with parsing Element-only HTML strings.

[How to get an HTML element from a string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery)

In my case, I have an HTML string **combining plain text with element(s)**.

```
var str = 'Some text ' + 
          '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="3" /> ' +
          '<input type="text" id="textField"/>';
```

I need the following 2 functions,
(1) Extract Plain Text from this string, (2) Extract Element by ID.

Examples:

(1) `getText(str) => 'Some text ';`

(2) `getElement(str, id) => jQuery element variable`

I was going to split by ID, and then split by `<`/`>` multiple times, then stitch together different strings, but that doesn't seem elegant, wondering if there are better ways.

Comment: In your case, can you modify the HTML you want to manipulate ? Because if you wrap your HTML/plain text with a `<div>` (for example), you can easily extract what you want with Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first requirement, just strip all the html from your string, you can do it using regex:

```
var stripedHtml = str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
console.log(stripedHtml) //Some text
```

Here is [a working example](https://regex101.com/r/y02iDY/1)

For the second use case, just parse it as html element and you're ready to go.

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = 'Some text ' + 
          '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="3" /> ' +
          '<input type="text" id="textField"/>';

el.getElementsByTagName( 'input' )
```

See here [a working example](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111) for the second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'Some text ' + 
          '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="3" /> ' +
          '<input type="text" id="textField"/>';
          
str2=str.split("<")        
          
          
for(i = 1; i < str2.length; i++){
   str2[i] = "<" + str2[i]
}

getID = document.getElementById("hiddenField")
     
console.log(getID)
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="3" /> 
<input type="text" id="textField"/>
```